# How to generate test report into file

Tags: terratest

I am currently running few terratests. On console I can see the log when add -v option but How do I generate test report of pass/failed tests? maybe in html or pdf format

Comment: did you try to follow the same approach of testing a GO application?

Answer (score 1):

> go test -timeout 30m | tee test_output.log terratest_log_parser
> -testlog test_output.log -outputdir test_output

This will:

- Create a file TEST_NAME.log for each test it finds from the test output containing the logs corresponding to that test.
- Create avsummary.log file containing the test result lines for each test.
- Create a report.xml file containing a Junit XML file of the test
  summary (so it can be integrated in your CI).